# Can I configure mediawiki to have a right side bar where links from the main page are explained?

Tags: php, navigation, content-management-system, mediawiki, wiki

My question is stated in the title but let me explain it more.

I have Mediawiki 1.21.3 installed on my server. The pages I want to create consist of one or two paragraphs only. They are definitions of meteorological terms just like in  http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Quasigeostrophic_approximation . They have a pretty good database but unfortunately it is only in English. 
I want to do something quite similar but with one big difference. When you look at the main page, a side bar containing all the links from the main page and their explanations to be visible to the right. Something like that:

```
|                   |         main page           |     right side
|left side with     |  .......<link 1>.........   |  link1:........
|navigation,        |  <link 2>................   |  link2:........
|and others         |  ........<link3>.........   |  ..............
|                   |  ........................   |  link3:........
```

What I dislike in Wikipedia is how I need to go back and forth between pages when the main page has many links I need to follow. I would gladly prefer the links with the beginning of their explanation to be visible to the right.

Can I do that with Mediawiki? If not, do you know any other CMS suitable for the purpose. I can always write it myself in PHP but if something better already exists, I will give it a try. I am new to wiki-like software, excuse me if the question is too simple. Google turned out with nothing useful. Thank you.

Comment: You mean like a Wiki Template? Is [this](http://idratherbewriting.com/2010/06/09/using-mediawiki-templates-to-organize-content-organizing-content-13/) what you are looking for?

Comment: You could do this with a MediaWiki extension. I'm not aware of any existing extension that would do exactly what you want, so you'd have to write our own, though. There are, however, extensions to show a preview of the target page in a popup when you hover the mouse over a link (here's [my own very primitive one](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Ilmari_Karonen/FancyTooltips)); you could at least use those as examples of how to do it.

Comment: This sounds promising to me. Would you please post this as an answer  to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your links into a [Template](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates) and display them on the right hand side.

You can create a template by adding [[template:swordfish]] on a page (in this case, swordfish is the name of the template I’m creating). You then add the custom set of links you want to include in that template page. To embed the template on your page, simply type {{template:swordfish}} where you want the template to appear.
The template navigation usually consists of links (styled however you want) pointing to your other wiki pages. Mediawiki is smart enough to dynamically change the class of the link that corresponds to the same page you’re viewing (the class becomes “selflink”), so you can create a unique style for the selflink class in your stylesheet.

The above was referenced from [this](http://idratherbewriting.com/2010/06/09/using-mediawiki-templates-to-organize-content-organizing-content-13/) link.

Here is an **example**

Create a new template. The easiest way to do this is to save a page with [[template:example]] on the page. Open that template and put your content inside. You can put links and descriptions in here. Save that page, go back to your initial page and inside it put {{template:example}} near the header. Style it so that it will show up on the right side: `style="float:right"` or whichever way you want to get it over there. Save that and you should bee good to go. Here is one I whipped up in about 5 minutes:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. An example: The main article have "apple" as link in the text. What I want to see to the right is the name of the link (in our case "apple") and the first paragraph of the explanation (apple is a fruit that grows ....). Those templates will give me the links only, if I understood the article you pointed at correctly.

Comment: A Template is basically a page that is embedded onto another, you can make it whatever you want to be although you have to maintain it. I will update my post with an example.

Comment: I understand your example but it doesn't seem to be what I am looking for. The page and its links should be connected by some reference in the database so a user could say "Give me the all links for page "N" and grab their own pages if they exist". It doesn't sound complicated to me. The question is if Mediawiki have the functionality to do this?